# windows 7 and oem disks

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, oem

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Legal to install an OEM license of Windows 7 in VMWare Fusion?](https://superuser.com/questions/94237/legal-to-install-an-oem-license-of-windows-7-in-vmware-fusion)
>   [Installing XP with out manufacturers original XP restore disk, possiable with OEM disk?](https://superuser.com/questions/100766/installing-xp-with-out-manufacturers-original-xp-restore-disk-possiable-with-oem)

dell sent me a laptop preloaded with 7 pro oem. the oem disk package was sealed. can i use that oem disk to load on another dell pc or a non dell desktop?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://superuser.com/questions/94237/legal-to-install-an-oem-license-of-windows-7-in-vmware-fusion (from a slightly different perspective)

Comment: This question - http://superuser.com/questions/100766/installing-xp-with-out-manufacturers-original-xp-restore-disk-possiable-with-oem - also covers some of the same ground. A search for "oem" here will turn up more

Answer (score 3):

Technically Yes (up to a point), Legally No.

The Dell OEM Windows disk will install and activate on pretty much any Dell hardware, however, you are only permitted to use it on the machine you bought it with as that is what the licence is tied to.

If you have other Dell machines that have lost the Media but are licensed for the same edition of Windows, there is no harm using it to restore.

Comment: However I try to answer this, my answer still sounds like yours!  .. Dell OEM CDs are just generic and do not have product keys built-in. Great for using as frisbees in the office. It is the product key (on the sticker on your computer - under the battery probably) which is tied to a single computer, not the CD itself.

Comment: Correct, this is not legal in any way, shape or form.